# Filtering out non-English results from Bing Web API v7

Tags: http-headers, bing, bing-api

Currently, the API returns results with varying languages, denoted by the "language" property in the response JSON. However, I need to filter those results with only "language": "en" without reducing the number of results I get (therefore, if possible, the filtering is done server-side).

I tried "setLang=en" in the query and "Accept-Language: en" (tested separately as advised in the reference). However, I still get foreign results.

Is there a way to get only English results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with **mkt=en-us** in the query?

Comment: Wow, that worked out nicely. Totally skipped my mind to include that